# Link only answer - with a comment what do you do?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing and came across this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/147300/4797 (EDIT: looks like it was voted to be deleted and was removed). The answer was

> Same issue i was facing in top links and found a very helpful blog
> here    http://rltsquare.com/blog/?p=183
>
> The way of explaining the solution was great and I just followed steps to overcome my problem
>
> **COMMENT:** While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link
> for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page
> changes.

It has a comment to update the answer, rather than vote to delete I skipped but I can see that a scenario like this is a bit confusing:

> Khoa TruongDinh reviewed this 7 mins ago: Recommend Deletion
>
> Rakesh reviewed this 24 mins ago: Looks OK
>
> fschmengler reviewed this 33 mins ago: Delete
>
> 7ochem reviewed this 34 mins ago: Recommend Deletion
>
> Siarhey Uchukhlebau reviewed this 39 mins ago: Recommend Deletion

So the comment would have been present - is this an automatic delete scenario? Should we not give an opportunity to the person answering to update the answer?

It seems that SE would benefit from a "snooze button" of 24 hours to allow people to update there own flagged answers rather than have them quietly deleted.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody is going to check again in 24hours or more.
The user can still edit the answer and notify an admin that the answer can be undeleted.
It happened before and I restored a few answers after they were edited.

Comment: So I should vote to delete? And the check again was to have a function that would wait 24 hours before re-entering the voting queue.

Comment: yes, vote to delete.